# Retrofit Get Data Object

Tags: java, retrofit

I have a data like this, and i want get report and criteria data.

```
{
    "response_code": 200,
    "message": "Your report data has been loaded.",
    "data": {
        "report": [
            {
                "id_report": 1,
                "report_name": "report name A"
            },
            {
                "id_report": 2,
                "report_name": "report name B"
            }
        ],
        "criteria": [
            {
                "id_criteria": 1,
                "criteria_name": "criteria name A"
            },
            {
                "id_criteria": 2,
                "criteria_name": "criteria name B"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And i get data in java using retrofit. And this is my java class.

GetReport.java

```
    @SerializedName("response_code")
    private int response_code;
    @SerializedName("status")
    private boolean status;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    Call<Data> listData;
```

Data.java

```
    @SerializedName("report")
    private List<Report> reportList;
    @SerializedName("criteria")
    private List<Criteria> criteriaList;
```

And this how i call the data.

```
public void populateData() {
        Call<GetReport> getReportCall = apiInterface.getReportCall();
        getReportCall.enqueue(new Callback<GetReport>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetReport> call, Response<GetReport> response) {
                response.body().getListData().enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<Data> response) {
                        List<Report> reportList = response.body().getReportList();

                        Log.d("TAGGGGGGGGGG", String.valueOf(reportList.size()));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Data> call, Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetReport> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

When I run the program, my activity closes immediately. When I look at logcat, there is too much running log data so I can't see where the error is.

Comment: you can filter the log based on many criteria. at least you can directly filter logcat to show only error log. without log information, it is very difficult to help you to spot the issue

Comment: I would recommend you to use a httpLogging interceptor with a http client so you will be able to see in the logcat all the information about your retrofit get, post, put, etc. And you can try using Log.d all around your program to see where it starts to give you problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to attempt and solve your problem with the following code. I copied and pasted the JSON you provided above at JSONbin.io so that I can be able to call it using an API call. I did not modify the structure of the JSON at all.

App build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
```

GetReport.java

```
package com.example.retrofitapp;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class GetReport {

@SerializedName("response_code")
int response_code;

@SerializedName("message")
String message;

@SerializedName("data")
Data data;

public int getResponse_code() {
    return response_code;
}

public void setResponse_code(int response_code) {
    this.response_code = response_code;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}}
```

Data.java

```
package com.example.retrofitapp;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.List;

public class Data {

@SerializedName("report")
List<Report> reportList;

@SerializedName("criteria")
List<Criteria> criteriaList;

public List<Report> getReportList() {
    return reportList;
}

public void setReportList(List<Report> reportList) {
    this.reportList = reportList;
}

public List<Criteria> getCriteriaList() {
    return criteriaList;
}

public void setCriteriaList(List<Criteria> criteriaList) {
    this.criteriaList = criteriaList;
}}
```

Criteria.java

```
package com.example.retrofitapp;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class Criteria {

@SerializedName("id_criteria")
int id_criteria;

@SerializedName("criteria_name")
String criteria_name;

public Criteria(int id_criteria, String criteria_name) {
    this.id_criteria = id_criteria;
    this.criteria_name = criteria_name;
}

public int getId_criteria() {
    return id_criteria;
}

public void setId_criteria(int id_criteria) {
    this.id_criteria = id_criteria;
}

public String getCriteria_name() {
    return criteria_name;
}

public void setCriteria_name(String criteria_name) {
    this.criteria_name = criteria_name;
}}
```

Report.java

```
package com.example.retrofitapp;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class Report {

@SerializedName("id_report")
int id_report;

@SerializedName("report_name")
String report_name;

public Report(int id_report, String report_name) {
    this.id_report = id_report;
    this.report_name = report_name;
}

public int getId_report() {
    return id_report;
}

public void setId_report(int id_report) {
    this.id_report = id_report;
}

public String getReport_name() {
    return report_name;
}

public void setReport_name(String report_name) {
    this.report_name = report_name;
}}
```

RetrofitClient.java

```
package com.example.retrofitapp.api;
import com.google.gson.*;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {
public static Retrofit retrofit;

public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient(String baseUrl){
    if(retrofit==null){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}}
```

Constants.java

```
package com.example.retrofitapp;

public class Constants {
   public static String base_url = "https://api.jsonbin.io/";
}
```

Api.java

```
package com.example.retrofitapp.api;
import com.example.retrofitapp.GetReport;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;

public interface Api {

@Headers("Secret-key:$2a$10$WxkkTylkdR7NwGSoPwrfy.Odxtj7MR2vDtYZBp9cOd0SaYGVRmhOm")
@GET("/b/5ff8172e63e86571a2e35639")
Call<GetReport> getReport();

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.retrofitapp;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.example.retrofitapp.api.Api;
import com.example.retrofitapp.api.RetrofitClient;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      //call method here
      populateData();
    }

   private void populateData() {
      Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitClient(Constants.base_url);
      Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
      Call<GetReport> getReportCall = api.getReport();

      //make asynchronous request
      getReportCall.enqueue(new Callback<GetReport>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(Call<GetReport> call, Response<GetReport> response) { 
            if(response.code()  == 200){
                GetReport getReport = (GetReport) response.body();
                
                  //get response code
                int responseCode = getReport.getResponse_code();
                
                //get message 
                String message = getReport.getMessage();
                
                //get data
                Data data = getReport.getData();
                
                //get reports(loop)
                for(Report report : data.getReportList()){
                    //your report here
                }

                //get criteria(loop)
                for(Criteria criteria : data.getCriteriaList()){
                    //your criteria here
                }
              }
           }
          @Override
          public void onFailure(Call<GetReport> call, Throwable t) {
            //do something if the request failed
          }
      });

  }}
```

That is how I solved it.